# Booting multiple Ubuntu's in a system

Tags: dual-boot

I having Ubuntu 11.10, Windows7 and Windows8 installed for now.

I also want to install UbuntuStudio.
I have tried installing it into a separate partition.

But, that did not load.

Only the Ubuntu 11.10(with WindowsLoader[windows7 & windows8]) loads.
The newly installed UbuntuStudio(based on Ubuntu 12.04) doesn't load up. The installation went successful.
How am I supposed to load that also?

Comment: There is no specific reason why it wouldn't work. You need to have the install done correctly, and then add it to your bootloader ofcourse, but without specific information what is happening (what does "doesn't load up" mean? do you get an error? what do you see? what do you expect? why do you expect it) it's impossible to say

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That depends on how many (primary) partitions you already have.

AFAIK only 4 primary partitions or 3 primary partitions and 1 extended partition, which can be subdivided into multiple logical partitions, are possible to be created on any hard drive. Many operating systems need to be running on an active primary partition to be bootable.

So if you already have 3 operating systems (probably on 3 primary partitions) and maybe one SWAP or data partition, you cannot create an additional primary partition (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_partitioning#PC_partition_types) for more information).

---

Nevertheless you actually don't need to seperately install Ubuntu Studio, as all the additional packages are available though the official packet sources. You can find a list of the packages [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuStudio/PackageList).

Comment: Yeah, Its 4 primary partitions that anyone can have. I have 3 so far & i wish to have this 4th OS in the new drive which i reserved.

Comment: And [link](http://askubuntu.com/users/138369/craven)Craven , I liked the look and feel of that enlightment DesktopEnvironment. But, it was missing a few Gnome features which i love.(dashboard, pressing Ctrl + Alt+T for getting a new terminal window, etc) If you can guide me on getting these in Studio, i will be switching to UBUNTUStudio itself(by removing the existing natty)What do u say buddy

Comment: Linux does *not* have to be installed in a primary partition to boot.

Comment: @user128677 - you can easily install other GUIs via terminal (i.e. **Gnome 2** [`gnome-panel`], **Gnome 3** [`gnome-shell`], **KDE** [`kubuntu-desktop`], **Unity** [`unity`], **XFCE** [`xfce4`] or others). I personally prefer Gnome 3, but that's just personal taste.

Most of those GUIs provide the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: Okay, confirm me one thing, can we have GNOME3 in UBUNTUSTUDIO, and can we switch to the existing xfce later on,?

Comment: You can always install any GUI via terminal and should be able to choose between them right before you logon.

Answer (score 2):

Run `sudo update-grub` in Ubuntu and it should find and add ubuntustudio to the menu.

Also 11.10 reaches end of life in a few weeks, so you should upgrade.